# From bootstrap Grid columns to carousel

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

So this is what I’m hoping to accomplish.

I currently have a bootstrap grid displaying 1 row and 4 columns.
On desktop devices the 4 columns appears next to each other
On tablets they appear in a 2 x 2 grid and in Mobile devices they appear 4 rows with 1 column.

Is it possible to make it so that when in tablet or mobile to have a carousel that I can slide between the 4 columns? So that when in Tablet there are 2 slides with two of the columns in each slide and when in mobile 4 slides with 1 column in each slide?

Here is my current grid code.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="how container">
  <div class="title">SUBSCRIBE IN JUST 4 EASY STEPS</div>
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="height:200px;">
      <span>SIGN UP</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="height:200px;">
      <span>SELECT AGE GROUP</span>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 d-block d-lg-none"></div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="height:200px;">
      <span>CHOOSE A SUBSCRIPTION PLAN</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="height:200px;">
      <span>HAVE FUN</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center pt-3">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">GET STARTED</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *Bootstrap* is the only library you're allowed to use, I would imagine you would have to have duplicate contents and show/hide one of them on different breakpoints for carousels or just regular 4-column content.

If that's not the case, I would highly recommend you to use [OwlCarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)! That has everything you're looking for.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="how container">
    <h4 class="title">
        SUBSCRIBE IN JUST 4 EASY STEPS
    </h4>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img src="https://loremflickr.com/600/200?random=1" 
                    class="figure-img img-fluid w-100" />
                <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                    SIGN UP
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, basically you just need a wrapper with a class `.owl-theme` that wraps a collection of `.item`s. Inside each item, you can have any content you want. Here I just demonstrated to have a `<figure />` inside of each item.

#### JavaScript

Make sure you've loaded `jQuery` first, then the javascript file of *OwlCarousel*, and then 2 style files: 1 core css and 1 theme. Installation details are documented [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html).

```js
$(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 0,
        nav: false,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            768:{
                items:2
            },
            992:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See, in the responsive option, this is where you define how many items you want per break point. More info from their documentation site [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html)!

#### Result

[image]

[image]

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/mvn3k08u/22/

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer. It worked perfectly